# stretch and shrink a row instead of a column

Tags: android, android-layout, layout

I'm looking to lay out a view similar to how TableLayout works, which can automatically shrink and stretch columns, except I want a row to be stretched and shrunk.

Basically I want to have a fixed-height button (dp) button at the top of the screen, a fixed-height button (dp) at the bottom of the screen, and an ImageView in the middle.  I want the ImageView to be stretched or shrunk as needed to accomodate the two fixed-height buttons.

Using a TableLayout with orientation=vertical doesn't seem to do the trick.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use relative layout to do waht you need. Attach the two buttons to the top and buttom respectively. Then for the image you can align its top to the buttom of top button and its buttom to top of buttom button.

Comment: Interesting.  What I ended up doing is using weights on a LinearLayout instead.  I made the two buttons have weight "0.0" and the image have weight "1.0".  I think I may also have made the image's width and height be "fill_parent".  It seems to work, but I wonder whether the RelativeLayout approach might be more efficient.  Probably so.

Comment: In fact I use RelativeLayout in most cases - its very flexible, and allows for good ways to support multiple screen sizes easily.